# Passing date from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime, type-conversion

I'm well aware that this topic has a lot of threads on it but I am unable to find any solution to my problem. I have a few text fields and a DataGridView in my windows form application. Also, a search where I can search between 2 DateTimePickers (2 DateTimePickers and a button).

This is the code that I am passing parameters to Postgresql table with:

```
private void addParameters(string str)
    {
      
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nametxt.Text.Trim());
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("number", numbertxt.Text.Trim());
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", User.uname.Trim());
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", User.pw.Trim());
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date1", date1.Value.Date);
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date2", date2.Value.Date);
        Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date3", date3.Value.Date);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.deletepass))
        {
            Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("deletepass", User.deletepass.Trim());
        }

        if (str == "Update" || str == "Delete" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.id))
        {
            Connection.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", this.id);
        }
        Connection.con.Close();
    }
```

Button click:

```
private void savebtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       Connection.sql = "INSERT INTO dbTable(name, number, username, password, date1, date2, date3)" +
                                        " VALUES(@name, @number, @username, @password, @date1, @date2, @date3)";

                execute(Connection.sql, "Insert"); <-----
   }
```

Execute method:

```
private void execute(string mySQL, string param)
    {
        Connection.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(mySQL, Connection.con);
        addParameters(param);
        Connection.PerformConnection(Connection.cmd); <---- public static for DataTable 
        Connection.con.Close();
    }
```

Connection is a class that contains info about local server connection. Columns in PQSQL table are defined to be DATE columns, and everything works just fine when local time on PC is set to d.MM.yyyy. format. Even better if I install the app on a PC that has d/MM/yyyy format, it still works just fine. But the problem occurs when I try to filter DGV entries from date1 to date2.

Search button code:

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "Date1")
        {
            Connection.sql = "SELECT * FROM dbTable WHERE date1::TIMESTAMP BETWEEN " +
                "(split_part('" + dtpFrom.Text + "', '.',2)||'/'||split_part('" + dtpFrom.Text + "', '.',1)||'/'||split_part" +
                "('" + dtpFrom.Text + "', '.',3))::TIMESTAMP AND (split_part('" + dtpTo.Text + "', '.',2)||'/'||split_part" +
                "('" + dtpTo.Text + "', '.',1)||'/'||split_part('" + dtpTo.Text + "', '.',3))::TIMESTAMP";

            Connection.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(Connection.sql, Connection.con);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.SelectCommand = Connection.cmd;
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            grid.DataSource = dt;
            Connection.con.Close();
        }
```

So, when I set picker1 and picker2 to some dates that I want to search between, I get this error: **Npgsql.PostgresException: '22008: date/time field value out of range: "15/12/2020"'** (When tested on PC that has d/MM/yyyy format, but on d.MM.yyyy works just fine) I've tried multiple conversions and what not, to no avail. Any hits of how I could solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `var timestampFrom = dtpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString("d");`.
When you change your PCs date settings, the `ToString´ method prints dates for that format. You need to use your databases format, [here is a list and docu how to make custom formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0). Do not mix up displayed values (in UI), with stored values (actual data in DB, mostly it's stored as timestamp).

Comment: Also: please, please, please(!) read this article about [SQLi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15) and re-write your sql query as explained in the article. It's not save what you are doing here.

Comment: @nilsK Thank you for answering, I'm well aware of possible SQL injections but I'm also still learning. Will rewrite the code for SQL when I get a better sense of how I should actually do it. I'm not sure that I completely understand where is should put var timestampFrom = dtpFrom.SelectedDate.ToString("d"); in my code and how to use it properly, could you provide me with an example maybe?